# Print a document bypassing printer dialog window in my application

Tags: reactjs, electron-builder, thermal-printer, printers, printdialog

We have an application that is developed only on ReactJs and built using electronJS. In our application, we send our bills to a default printer ( Thermal Printer ). Everytime we want to print, print dialog window will open that will show the printer setup. Then only we will be able to print the bills.

Now what we want is to bypass the printer dialog window so that data will directly go to the printer when print button is clicked from the app. Can we get any inputs on this? We heard about webserial API but need some solid inputs to work on this.